# Equation with conjugate (complex numbers)

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve this equation:

$(z-1)^3=9(\bar{z}-1)$

The problem is the conjugate.

$w=z-1$

Then:

$w^3=9(\bar{z}-1)$

Is there a relation between $\bar{z}$ and $w$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\overline z - 1 = \overline{z-1}$$

Comment: Then $(\overline{z-1})=\overline{w}$?

Comment: @gefavasej `\overline{}` is better than `\bar{}` for writing complex conjugates, but yes, $\overline{z-1} = \overline w$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(z-1)^3=9(\overline z-1)$, then $\bigl|(z-1)^3\bigr|=9\bigl|\overline z-1\bigr|$, which means that $z=1$ or that $|z-1|^2=9$. So, either $z=1$ or $z=1+3(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ for some $\theta$. Can you take it from here?